# In linux how to run piece of code without getting preempted in user mode

Tags: linux

```
thread-stop-preemption
//code to run
thread-start-preemption
```

a piece of code is running in a thread,

are atomic functions are available in user mode?

Answer (score 1):

Linux doesn't offer very good behavior for real-time applications.
Unless your application really is real-time you should change your code to use normal synchronization primitives (e.g. mutexes, condition variables etc.)

But if you really think you need your thread not to be interrupted you *might* get away (but not really) with the real-time policies mentioned in [`sched(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) e.g. `SCHED_FIFO`. If you choose to go down that route you can influence a thread's scheduling using [`sched_setattr(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html).

### More warning

Before using this for anything with [hard real-time constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) consider a vanilla Linux kernel itself is probably not the tool for the job: although the scheduler will try to keep your thread running I don't think it "guarantees" it.